# How to get p values for odds ratios from an ordinal regression in r

Tags: r, p-value, ordinal

I am trying to get the p values for my odds ratio from an ordinal regression using r.

I previously constructed my p values on the log odds like this

```
scm <- polr(finaloutcome ~ Size_no + Hegemony + Committee, data = data3, Hess = TRUE)
(ctable <- coef(summary(scm)))
```

Calculate and store p value

```
p <- pnorm(abs(ctable[, "t value"]), lower.tail = FALSE) * 2
## combined table
(ctable <- cbind(ctable, "p value" = p))
```

I created by odds ratios like this:

```
ci <- confint.default(scm) 
exp(coef(scm))
## OR and CI 
exp(cbind(OR = coef(scm), ci))
```

However, I am now unsure how to create the p values for the odds ratio. Using the previous method I got:

```
(ctable1 <- exp(coef(scm)))
p1 <- pnorm(abs(ctable1[, "t value"]), lower.tail = FALSE) * 2
(ctable <- cbind(ctable, "p value" = p1))
```

However i get the error: Error in ctable1[, "t value"] : incorrect number of dimensions

Odds ratio output sample:

| Size | Hegem | Committee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9.992240e-01 | 6.957805e-02 | 1.204437e-01 |

Data sample:

|  | finaloutcome | Size_no | Committee | Hegemony |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 54 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 127 | 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 127 | 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 22 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 54 | 2 | 0 |
| 7 | NA | 11 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 3 | 54 | 2 | 0 |
| 9 | 3 | 22 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 | 53 | 3 | 1 |
| 11 | 2 | 53 | 3 | 1 |
| 12 | 2 | 53 | 3 | 1 |
| 13 | 2 | 53 | 3 | 1 |
| 14 | 2 | 53 | 3 | 1 |
| 15 | 2 | 53 | 3 | 1 |
| 16 | 2 | 120 | 3 | 0 |
| 17 | 2 | 120 | 3 | 0 |
| 18 | 1 | 22 | 1 | 1 |
| 19 | 1 | 22 | 1 | 1 |
| 20 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 21 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 22 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 23 | 2 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 24 | 2 | 35 | 1 | 1 |
| 25 | 1 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 26 | 1 | 164 | 4 | 1 |
| 27 | 1 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 28 | 2 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 29 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 30 | 2 | 54 | 2 | 0 |
| 31 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 32 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 33 | 2 | 54 | 2 | 0 |
| 34 | 2 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 35 | 2 | 22 | 1 | 1 |
| 36 | 4 | 53 | 3 | 1 |
| 37 | 2 | 35 | 1 | 1 |
| 38 | 1 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 39 | 5 | 54 | 2 | 0 |
| 40 | 7 | 164 | 4 | 1 |
| 41 | 5 | 54 | 2 | 0 |
| 42 | 1 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 43 | 7 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 44 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 45 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 46 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 47 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 48 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 49 | 2 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 50 | 2 | 22 | 1 | 1 |
| 51 | 2 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 52 | 2 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 53 | 6 | 13 | 1 | 1 |
| 54 | 6 | 13 | 1 | 1 |
| 55 | 6 | 13 | 1 | 1 |
| 56 | 6 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 57 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 58 | 3 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 59 | 1 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 60 | 1 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 61 | 8 | 35 | 1 | 1 |
| 62 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 63 | 8 | 35 | 1 | 1 |
| 64 | 6 | 30 | 2 | 1 |
| 65 | 8 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 66 | 4 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 67 | 5 | 30 | 2 | 1 |
| 68 | 5 | 54 | 2 | 0 |
| 69 | 7 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 70 | 5 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 71 | 5 | 54 | 2 | 0 |
| 72 | 5 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 73 | 5 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 74 | 5 | 54 | 2 | 0 |
| 75 | 5 | 54 | 2 | 0 |
| 76 | 1 | 11 | 1 | 1 |
| 77 | 3 | 22 | 1 | 1 |
| 78 | 3 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 79 | 6 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 80 | 2 | 22 | 1 | 1 |
| 81 | 8 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 82 | 8 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 83 | 4 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 84 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 85 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 86 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 87 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 88 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 89 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 90 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 91 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 92 | 2 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 93 | 8 | 193 | 4 | 1 |
| 94 | 6 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 95 | 5 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 96 | 5 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 97 | 5 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 98 | 5 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 99 | 5 | 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 100 | 5 | 12 | 4 | 1 |

Comment: Hi! If possible, add small sample of your data to better find an answer to your problem. In your case, it would help sample data that allows to fit the polr() function, and still produces an error.

Comment: @JuanBosco thank you I have added some sample data and the odds ratio outputs

Answer (score 0):

I usually use lm or glm to create my model (mdl <- lm(…) or mdl <- glm(…)). Then I use summary on the object to see these values. More than this, you can use the [Yardstick](https://yardstick.tidymodels.org/) and [Broom](https://broom.tidymodels.org/). I recommend the book [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/). There is a great explanation about modeling and using the Tidymodels packages.

Comment: thank you, I have tried using the Broom tidy functions but it only outputs the odds ratio values, do you know a way of writing the code for the odds ratios that would include the p value?

Comment: I think the issue is specifically of how to get the p value for the odds ratios rather than the log odds which an ordinal regression would normally output

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same difficulty.

I finally used the fonction tidy from the broom package: https://broom.tidymodels.org/reference/tidy.polr.html

```
library(broom)
tidy(scm, p.values = TRUE)
```

This does not yet work if you have categorical variables with more than two levels, or missing values.